# How to add value in dictionary if key exists instead of replace it

Tags: python, dictionary, append

The below will replace values in the dictionary rather than adding them. ie if there are two wallets with a USD balance I would like the dictionary to add them together rather than replace the first entry with the second entry. Please can someone advise how to do this.

```
for acc in response["accounts"]:
    balances = {}
    for wallet in acc["_embedded"]["wallets"]:
        if wallet["balance"] != "0":
            balances[wallet["currency"]] = wallet["balance"]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share your complete code.

Comment: 1. you assign a new dict to `balances` each time. 2. use `from collections import Counter` instead of standard dict. It automatically initializes new keys to 0 and supports operations like update for easy incrementation of values.

Comment: Use `defaultdict(int)` instead of `{}`, or say `balances.setdefault(wallet["currency"], 0) += float(wallet["balance"])`

Comment: Do you want the balance to be a string or a number?

Answer (score 0):

What I got from your question is that you want to add the balance to the currency key?
try the below code , the .get(key) would check if key exists if it does it would add the amount to current , else would create a new key with initial balance.

```
for acc in response["accounts"]:
    balances = {}
    for wallet in acc["_embedded"]["wallets"]:
        if wallet["balance"] != "0":
            if balances.get(wallet["currency"]):
                balances[wallet["currency"]] += wallet["balance"]
            else:
                balances[wallet["currency"]] = wallet["balance"]
```